# What particles do these Feynman diagram lines represent?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, virtual-particles

[image]

What particles could be represented by A and B (labels I have added myself - this is not a homework question)?

For A, it looks like it's supposed to be a photon, but I was under the impression that an EM interaction cannot change quark flavour?

For B, is it some sort of virtual pion?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Ah yes, that was a bit stupid of me. For B, I'm a little confused still, because this diagram is supposed to be representing $\pi^0$ decay, so why is a $\pi^0$ in the middle of the interaction? Is it because it's virtual?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Yeah, I also realised I had misinterpreted it (and got $\pi^\pm$ and $\pi^0$ mixed up, no less). I've come to the conclusion that it's a u (or d for the 2nd case). So it's definitely virtual, then?

Comment: By the way, the arrows on the antifermion lines are backwards. This is a common mistake. Incoming antifermions point away from the vertex. Outgoing antifermions point towards the vertex.

Comment: @dukwon I didn't think this was a mistake, merely a matter of convention. My lecturer said that all of his Feynman diagrams would show the 'direction' of the particles to avoid confusion. Don't FDs not need arrows anyway?

Comment: Fermion lines definitely need arrows. Feynman diagrams are foremost a tool for constructing integrals to calculate amplitudes. There are rules for how things should be drawn. If your lecturer wants to draw diagrams that kind-of look like Feynman diagrams, but aren't, then he can go ahead, but he should really make it clear that's what he's doing.

Comment: @dukwon Wikipedia seems to confirm what you are saying. Whilst I think it's a good idea to introduce FDs in this way to avoid confusion, I do wish lecturers were clearer about so many things...

Answer (score 1):

A can be photon, Z or gluon.
B can be u or d quark.

Answer (score 0):

As AccidentalFourierTransform has pointed out, there is no change of flavour in A, because the $u$ and $\bar{u}$ are annihilating, so it is a photon.

For the $\pi^0$ decay, B is a virtual $u$ or $d$.

Comment: How do you know that A is not gluon?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform you don't know what is the energy. For high energy $\alpha_{EM}>\alpha_s$

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform there is no indication on the first diagram that this is  a pion decay. Anyway pion cannot decay to any baryon.

Comment: @Veritas what the diagram is referring to is the fact that the $\eta$ and $\eta'$ masses are different from predicted by the quark model. "This can be understood by the fact that a pure (e.g.) uu state can change to (e.g.) a dd as follows [DIAGRAM] so that the flavour eigenstates are not (necessarily) the mass eigenstates." - quoted from source

Comment: I'm wondering whether that it's meant to be a photon because of the type of line, or whether it was left blank intentionally as there are several options